# websocket php ratchet with server vps 2 from hostinger using centos operation

Tags: php, apache, websocket, vps

1. hello all im try to make chat as real time im used websocket with
   php ratchet packege  and this my code : in my file server.php this
   code

   use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
   use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
   use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
   use MyApp\Chat;

   ```
   require dirname(__DIR__) . '/rat/autoload.php';

   $server = IoServer::factory(
       new HttpServer(
           new WsServer(
               new Chat()
           )
       ),
      8000
   );

   $server->run();
   ```

also my secend file is a script js in  message.php :

```
      var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');                
    conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
    };
```

2. please what i should to do   w://loclahost:8000 is correct ? or
   should i changed in my host name ? or domain name? or what

> secend qution what i should use port
> i had searched in google but i find more article that telk about httpd i cant f
> ind my answers please